# Let $I,J$ ideals, then $I \otimes_R J \simeq IJ$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $I,J$ ideals of $R$. Is true that $I \otimes_R J \simeq IJ $ ?

If not, have conditions on $I,J$ such that it is true?

Comment: Yes, but I want to know if have conditions over $I,J$ that makes this result true

Comment: For example, if $J=M$ is a flat module, the result is true

Comment: In general, exists a condition over $I,J$?

Comment: The given answer proves that the map $I \otimes_R J \to IJ, \, a \otimes b \mapsto ab$ is bijective if and only if $\operatorname{Tor}_1^R(R/I,J)=0$.